# Twitter api giving blank response if tweet starts wil @username

Tags: php, twitter

I am using [twitter-api-php](https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php). I am posting statuses and it works well. The only problem is, when the tweet starts with @username, its returning a blank page. I don't know whats wrong. This problem is not just with me, when googling about it, found another person with same query,

Here is the code I am using to post.

```
$settings = array(
    'oauth_access_token' => "ACCESS_TOKEN",
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => "ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET",
    'consumer_key' => CONSUMER_KEY,
    'consumer_secret' => CONSUMER_SECRET
);

$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json";
$str = "@sourabh_bajaj this is a sample tweet";
$requestMethod = 'POST';

$twitter=new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
echo $twitter->setPostfields(
    array(
        "trim_user" => 1,
        "status" => $str
    )
)->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)->performRequest();
```

This works well if we remove @sourabh_bajaj from the start of the message.

Comment: It is far more likely that there are two people out there who have bugs in their code than the Twitter API has such a critical bug with no documentation or report on it. Post some of your code!

Comment: Added some code and explaination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Your Exact Issue

You haven't gotten the latest version of the library you're using!

[This commit](https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php/commit/b8cf4c19f720cc87491252b3d029b70b134261a9) on github shows the fix for your exact problem:

```
$array['status'] = sprintf("\0%s", $array['status']);
```

Basically, adding a blank space or a full stop **is not** how to fix this. I added a null character to the beginning, and all tweets (and @reply tweets - which won't work properly with full stops) now work great.

This is due to a limitation with cURL, and @ symbols at the beginning (cURL thinks you're trying to upload a file when you do this).

So, to reiterate:

**Re-download TwitterAPIExchange.php**, and keep checking out the changelog. You'll find this solves your issue.